# Java - Load data to memory once, and use it multiple times

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have a Java program, which needs to use a function from a imported source package that loads 2GB data into the memory and use it to do the calculation.

However every time when I call the function, the loading process is processed, which is very time consuming.

My program's structure is like:

```
Socket Server (listening on a port)

|_ Multi Server Thread (Work as a input stream reader)

...|_ Sample Protocol (deal with the input steam using the data related functions)
```

I know this is a question too wide, but:

1. Are there any general idea that I can run the loading only once and use it to do all the calculation afterwards?
2. IF I import the package in the Top Level (in socket server), will that help me accelerate the loading process somehow?
3. What is the more common method used by the enterprise?

Comment: It's quite a broad question but if you really want to and can store all that data in your heap memory (which will likely be a lot more than the 2GB persisted data due to object overhead), simply assign an instance or static-scoped variable with your processed data and verify it holds it already before starting the loading process. You can also add synchronized mechanisms to safely refresh it in the background if needed.

Comment: I recently had this issue with some data here in my office. I went about it seven ways from Sunday. You can't get around the fact that loading it once is very time consuming, and in one instance it was so much data that it caused heap allocation errors on that box. You can't accelerate it much, but if you can load it once at the top level it exposes it for all other classes to use it. You will also need to synchronize it so all threads do go crashing into the data together.

Comment: Be sure you understand the effects of stale pointers as seen from different threads. When one thread saves your 2GB of data in a variable, another thread can still see `null` and load the data again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this question did not get any answer for a long time, here is 
a small summary:

It turns out in the current method I used, if I load the lib in the highest level (Socket Server), we can make sure that for every thread in it we don't need to load the library again.

In the enterprise level, there are better multi-thread functions for java, like:

newCachedThreadPool()

newFixedThreadPool()

newSingleThreadExecutor()

newScheduledThreadPool()

For example we can use them like,

`ExecutorService fixedThreadPool() = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);`

`Future<T> future1 = singleThreadPool.submit(new MyRunnable());`

`singleThreadPool.execute(new MyRunnable);`

`singleThreadPool.shutdown();`

which might be useful in real practice.